# Do I need schengen visa if I have 3 hour layover at Zurich and then connecting flight to Toronto?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit-visas

I am flying next month from Mumbai-Zurich-Toronto. The layover at Zurich airport is 3 hrs and then I have a connecting flight to Toronto. Do I need a Schengen Visa?

There is also another flight from Mumbai - London-Toronto, so if there is a layover of 3 hours in London do I need any transit visa?

Comment: Whether you need a visa depends on your nationality. Can you please edit it in?